# When i made a new build for react and deploy on server, i have to remove the cache to see new changes. Is there any proper solution for it

Tags: reactjs, build, browser-cache, webpack-dev-server

When I made new build for production and deploy then the new changes reflect after i clear my cache. is there any webpack or other settings wit which i can clear cache on server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `webpack`. Check out this tutorial to add a unique hash to filename each time you release a build.
https://powerspace.tech/how-to-cache-busting-with-webpack-5131b4af8826

Answer (score 0):

If your browser applies an aggressive cache maybe chaging filenames does not helps. If it chaches the http response with html then it will use the cached version of your js files based non the cached html.
It's better to manage cache in http headers or make use of reverse proxies.